# Local extrema given the graph of a function's derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

I am given a graph of the derivative of a function and answered most of the questions, but am still stuck at answering where the local extrema are. I had a sample question to reference from and it looked like the local minima were where $y=0$ on the derivative graph, but this was wrong. Can somebody help me out please? Thanks.

Comment: $y'=0$ gives the extrema. For increasing values of $x$, if $y'$ decreases, vanishes and increases, then it is a minimum.  For increasing values of $x$, if $y'$ increases, vanishes and decreases, then it is a maximum. Is this better ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici wow sorry my question was worded really bad. So I am trying to look for the local extrema of the original function, f. Not f'.

Comment: I was speaking about the original function. Curvature (concave or convex) is given by the sign of $y''$ at the place where $y'=0$. Your question was well worded !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Oh I got it now! Thanks!

Comment: You are very welcome ! I am glad to have helped you.

Comment: Just note that $y^{\prime}=0$ is not sufficient for an extremum. You also need $y^{\prime\prime}\neq 0$, otherwise you have a saddle point.

Comment: I am a bit confused as y’ can increase/decrease, level off, then decrease/increase without having a value y’ = 0. In such a case, could the point at which it levels off be considered max/min without having y’ = 0, or is it also a requirement that y’ = 0 at the point at which the derivative graph levels off. If I had to guess, we are checking where y increases/decreases using y’ = 0 critical points, but am not sure if I am correct.